# Deep copying a PSObject

Tags: .net, powershell, deep-copy, psobject

I have a powershell script in which I do the following

```
$somePSObjectHashtables = New-Object Hashtable[] $somePSObject.Length;
$somePSObjects = Import-CSV $csvPath
0..($somePSObject.Length - 1) | ForEach-Object {
    $i = $_;
    $somePSObjectHashtables[$i] = @{};
    $somePSObject[$_].PSObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        $somePSObjectHashtables[$i][$_.Name] = $_.Value;
    }
}
```

I need to do this because I want to make several distinct copies of the data in the CSV to perform several distinct manipulations. In a sense I'm performing an "INNER JOIN" on the resulting array of [PSObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I can easily iterate through `$somePSObjectHashtables` with a [ForEach-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347608.aspx) and call [Hashtable.Clone()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.hashtable.clone.aspx) on each member of the array. I can then use `New-Object PSObject -Property $someHashTable[$i]` to get a deep copy of the PSObject.

My question is, is there some easier way of making the deep copy, without an intermediary Hashtable?

Comment: That's probably how I would have ended up solving such an issue.

Comment: Just to be sure about terms. `Hashtable.Clone()` makes shallow copies. Are we talking about deep copies or not?

Comment: Well, in this particular scenario, when data come from CSV, it will be *in fact* deep, because properties are either value types (deep copied, indeed) or strings (not deep copied but they are immutable, so we may consider them *deep copied* in that sense).

Comment: @RomanKuzmin You are right that Hashtable.Clone() does shallow copies.  I had an issue with nested hashtables where that fact manifested itself to my annoyance. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Does binary serialization approach work in your scenarios? It worked for me in a few simple tests.

Comment: I didn't rewrite the code yet. I'll mark it as correct when I do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For getting really deep copies we can use binary serialization (assuming that all data are serializable; this is definitely the case for data that come from CSV):

```
# Get original data
$data = Import-Csv ...

# Serialize and Deserialize data using BinaryFormatter
$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$bf = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
$bf.Serialize($ms, $data)
$ms.Position = 0
$data2 = $bf.Deserialize($ms)
$ms.Close()

# Use deep copied data
$data2
```

Comment: Apologies for the late accept. I [tested it](https://gist.github.com/2006846) an it worked. One thing I notices id that you had to explicitly cast Get-Date calls as DateTime or else the serializer would complain thatit could not serialize PSObject.

Comment: @Peter McEvoy, FYI, I have created a PowerShell serializer: [ConvertTo-Expression](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression)

Comment: Is there an object "depth" limit to this approach?

Comment: I am not aware of such a "depth". Maybe just the available memory is the limit. Also, cyclic references in the serialized graph, if any, should not be a problem, the binary serialization handles these.

Answer (score 13):

Note that here is a shorter, maybe a bit cleaner version of this (that I quite enjoy):

```
$data = Import-Csv .\test.csv

$serialData = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($data)

$data2 = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($serialData)
```

Note:
However, weirdly, it does not keep the ordering of ordered hashtables.

```
$data = [ordered] @{
    1 = 1
    2 = 2
}

$serialData = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Serialize($data)

$data2 = [System.Management.Automation.PSSerializer]::Deserialize($serialData)
$data2
```

Will output:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
2                              2
1                              1
```

While with other types it works just fine:

```
$data = [PsCustomObject] @{
    1 = 1
    2 = 2
}

$data = @(1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: In powershell 7.4 if your object contains scriptblocks, then this process will leave your scriptblock values as basic strings.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an even shorter one that I use as a function:

```
using namespace System.Management.Automation
function Clone-Object ($InputObject) {
    <#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Use the serializer to create an independent copy of an object, useful when using an object as a template
    #>
    [psserializer]::Deserialize(
        [psserializer]::Serialize(
            $InputObject
        )
    )
}
```