# Copy PowerShell dictionary into a variable

Tags: powershell, dictionary, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to clone a dictionary into a variable called `$backUp` using `.clone()` method, but it is failing with the error:

> Method invocation failed because 
>   [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, 
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.String, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]]
>   does not contain a method  named 'Clone'. At line:10 char:1
>   + $backUp = $originalKeyValuePairs.Clone()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

```
$originalKeyValuePairs = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$originalKeyValuePairs.add("key1", "value1")
$originalKeyValuePairs.add("key2", "value2")
$originalKeyValuePairs.add("key3", "value3")
$originalKeyValuePairs.add("key4", "value4")

Write-Output "This is the original dictionary" $originalKeyValuePairs

#Copy the "originalKeyValuePairs" into a variable
$backUp = $originalKeyValuePairs.Clone()

#update the 'key2' value to something else:
$originalKeyValuePairs["key2"] = "tempvalue"

#Now I'm done with updating the values. Now I want to restore my "$backUp" into the $originalKeyValuePairs
$originalKeyValuePairs = $backUp.clone()

Write-Output "Done with updating some of the value in original keyValuePairs and restore 'backUp' dictionary into 'originalKeyValuePairs'. Here is the unmodified dictionary" $originalKeyValuePairs
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to deep copy it instead of clone it. Check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204829/deep-copying-a-psobject)

```
$originalKeyValuePairs = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary``2[System.String,System.String]"
$originalKeyValuePairs.add("key1", "value1")
$originalKeyValuePairs.add("key2", "value2")
$originalKeyValuePairs.add("key3", "value3")
$originalKeyValuePairs.add("key4", "value4")

Write-Output "This is the original dictionary" $originalKeyValuePairs

#Copy the "originalKeyValuePairs" into a variable
$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$bf = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
$bf.Serialize($ms, $originalkeyvaluepairs)
$ms.Position = 0
$backup = $bf.Deserialize($ms)
$ms.Close()

#update the 'key2' value to something else:
$originalKeyValuePairs["key2"] = "tempvalue"

#Now I'm done with updating the values. Now I want to restore my "$backUp" into the $originalKeyValuePairs
$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$bf = New-Object System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
$bf.Serialize($ms, $backup)
$ms.Position = 0
$originalkeyvaluepairs = $bf.Deserialize($ms)
$ms.Close()

Write-Output "Done with updating some of the value in original keyValuePairs and restore 'backUp' dictionary into 'originalKeyValuePairs'. Here is the unmodified dictionary" $originalKeyValuePairs
```