# Unable to set iteratively values from array object to json objects

Tags: json, powershell

I am a newbie to powershell, and I am trying to create function that copies an object from a json data, creates new object from it and assigns different values to the max parameter. So far, different versions of my implementation assigns only the last value from an  array `$ParameterValues` to all the new objects created.

One solution, might be probabbly be to read the json data using a call by reference `[ref]$jsonData`. However, I am not even sure that is a thing in powershell.

--- Here is the sample json file:

```
"algorithms": {
    "obj0": {
      "command": "...",
      "parameters": {
        "min": 2.7,
        "max": 7
      }
    }
```

--- Function `Select-Member` helps select the object to copy

```
function Select-Member {
    [CmdLetBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$Path,
    
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [Object]$InputParameter
    )
    Write-Debug $InputParameter
    $Path -split '/' | ForEach-Object { $selected = $InputParameter } { $selected = $selected.$_ } { $selected }
}
```

--- Function `Set-Member` pastes the `new object` copied using `Select-Member` or overwrites the values of the `parameter` selected

```
function Set-Member {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(  
        [Object]$Value,
        [string[]]$Path,
        [Object]$Object
    )

    $Head, $Next, $Tail = $Path
    if (($null -eq $Next) -or (1 -gt $Next.Length)) {
        Add-Member -Passthru -Force -MemberType NoteProperty `
            -Input $Object -Name $Head -Value $Value
    }
    else {
        Add-Member -Passthru -Force -MemberType NoteProperty `
            -Input $Object -Name $Head `
            -Value (Set-Member -Value $Value -Path ([string[]]$Next + $Tail) -Object ($Object.$Head))
    }
}
```

--- `test-func` function uses `Select-Member` to select an object (`obj0` for example), then `Set-Member` adds new copies (`obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3`) of the object selected and then it should assign a new  value to `Max` iteratatively from `$ParameterValues` array.

```
function test-func {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position)]
        [string] $ObjectSelect,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position)]
        [string] $Parameter,
        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position)]
        [Object[]] $ParameterValues
    )
    $PathToPaste = ($ObjectSelect -Split '/', -2)[0] -Split '/'

    $JsonData = Get-content "$JSON_FILE" -raw | convertFrom-Json
    $ObjectSelected = Select-Member $ObjectSelect $JsonData

    [string]$NewObjName 
    foreach ($ele in $ParameterValues){
        $NewObjName = "obj" + $ele 
        Set-Member $ObjectSelected $NewObjName $JsonData.$PathToPaste
        $PathToParameter = $PathToPaste, $NewObjName, $Parameter-Split'/'
        Set-Member $ele $PathToParameter $JsonData
    }

    $JsonData | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32 | set-content "$JSON_FILE"
}
```

When I run the following command for example, `test-func -ObjectSelect algorithms/obj0  -Parameter parameters/max -ParameterValues 1,2,3` to iteratatively assign each value from the `$ParameterValues` to `max`, it sets only the last value from  the array to all the new objects created, `obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3`.

Here is the results I get. (Observe that the value `max` in the last three objects (`obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3`) are all identical = 3.

```
"algorithms": {
    "obj0": {
      "command": "...",
      "parameters": {
        "min": 2.7,
        "max": 7
      }
    },
    "obj1": {
      "command": "...",
      "parameters": {
        "min": 2.7,
        "max": 3
      }
    },
    "obj2": {
      "command": "...",
      "parameters": {
        "min": 2.7,
        "max": 3
      }
    },
    "obj3": {
      "command": "...",
      "parameters": {
        "min": 2.7,
        "max": 3
      }
    }
  }
```

The expected results should be like this (Observe that the value of `max` are 1, 2, 3 for the last three objects (`obj1`, `obj2`, `obj3`) respectively.):

```
"algorithms": {
    "obj0": {
      "command": "...",
      "parameters": {
        "min": 2.7,
        "max": 7
      }
    },
    "obj1": {
      "command": "...",
      "parameters": {
        "min": 2.7,
        "max": 1
      }
    },
    "obj2": {
      "command": "...",
      "parameters": {
        "min": 2.7,
        "max": 2
      }
    },
    "obj3": {
      "command": "...",
      "parameters": {
        "min": 2.7,
        "max": 3
      }
    }
  }
```

As of now, the only solution I have is using the following `for-each` loop in the test-func` function, which is definitely not professional. Notice it saves and reads again the json file on line 4 and 5. Like I said I am sure this is not professional as it will take up memory and time.

`foreach ($ele in $ParameterValues){ $NewObjName = "obj" + $ele  Set-Member $ObjectSelected $NewObjName $JsonData.$PathToPaste $JsonData | ConvertTo-Json -depth 32 | set-content "$JSON_FILE" $JsonData = Get-content "$JSON_FILE" -raw | convertFrom-Json $PathToParameter = $PathToPaste, $NewObjName, $Parameter-Split'/' Set-Member $ele $PathToParameter $JsonData }`

Comment: I didn't test your script (as I don' t see a difference between actual and expected) but I suspect it is related to [not all properties displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44429084/1701026) as your `$head` property name is probably not the same for all objects.

Comment: Hello @iRon if you look at the max parameter, the value I get for `obj1`, `obj2`, and `obj3` are all identical ie equal to 3, the last value passed to the `parameterValues` array.

Comment: Need to give sample json data otherwise your code is useless.

Comment: Hello @DougMaurer, thanks for your reply I have made some corrections and added the sample json file I have initially.

Comment: The other important part that is missing is select-member. You really, really should provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Hello @DougMaurer, I think the MRE is complete. Thanks.

Comment: The output I see when running your example command is not that just the max is set to 3, but instead each obj has 3 occurrences. 
`$a.obj2.parameters

min max
--- ---
2.7   3
2.7   3
2.7   3`

Comment: `$a.obj1

command parameters       
------- ----------       
abc     @{min=2.7; max=3}
abc     @{min=2.7; max=3}
abc     @{min=2.7; max=3}`

Comment: Remove  `| set-content "$JSON_FILE"` from your test func and look at the output to see if it's what you're expecting (besides the max value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue here is that in the loop, you are still referencing the initial object. So the last $ele passed will change the values of all new objects created in that way.

You to use `psobject.copy()` to create a copy of the new object. But there is a catch, this only creates a shallow copy, that is if you have nested objects (where the properties contain other objects), only the top-level values are copied. The child objects will reference each other.

Since you are trying to update the value of one of the parameters. You will have to introduce something like this in the for-loop.

```
$ThisObject = $JsonData.($TargetPath[...]).psObject.Copy()
$ThisObject.$TargetProperty =  $ParameterValues[$i]
$JsonData.($TargetPath[...])| Add-Member -Name "obj$($i+1)" -Value
         $ThisObject -MemberType NoteProperty
```

Another solution will be to create a deep copy, especially if you have multiple updates to make at different depths. For more on that, you can visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204829/deep-copying-a-psobject)

Comment: Thanks alot  . I evetually implemented an algorithm with the piece of code you shared. Earlier I did use a copy but the results werenät what I expected, I missed the part where it mentioned shallow copy. I will test using a deepcopy later. Thanks